# Possible to resample tifs in numpy array?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.3, numpy, resampling, array

I need to resample a large number of tif files. Is it possible to put the list of rasters in a numpy array and resample the array? I'm thinking this would be faster than looping through the list, but since resampling even one raster takes from 5 - 10 seconds normally, maybe it would cause a chokepoint.

Comment: What makes you think that resampling with one C-backend (Arc, GDAL,..) would be significantly faster than resampling with another C-backend (Numpy, Scipy,...)?

Comment: New to numpy, but my understanding is that numpy array operations are much faster than a for loop in a list. Is this incorrect? There are a lot of tifs.

Comment: Hard to tell unless you also provide a code example. But my guess is you are using a for loop to loop over 2D images and resample them one after another. In numpy you would also need to loop over all images unless you are planning to read all of them into a 3D array and resample in every dimension.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm misunderstanding numpy. I'm not applying a numerical function, and in any case, arcpy.Resample_management doesn't take an array. I'm going to close this thread.